# Как сделать айтемы ListView в виде карточек?

Tags: java, android

Возможно ли `ListView` сделать карточками, вроде такого?

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 4, accepted):

используйте в качестве айтема списка виджет [`CardView`](https://developer.android.com/intl/ru/reference/android/support/v7/widget/CardView.html)

```
<android.support.v7.widget.CardView
    android:id="@+id/card"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FEFEFE"
    android:layout_margin="8dp"
    app:cardCornerRadius="4dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">
        <ImageView
            android:id="@+id/icon"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:scaleType="centerCrop"/>
        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/text_header"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" />
    </LinearLayout>
</android.support.v7.widget.CardView>
```

Разметку внутри айтема скомпонуйте сами, как вам требуется, это только пример. Так же вам понадобится кастомный адаптер, чтобы биндить в этот айтем данные.

Answer (score 1):

Вкратце, способов очень много, зависит от версии. Например, с Android 6.0 (если память не изменяет) добавляется CardView. Если версии, младше, можно использовать всё что угодно от canvas до GridView.

PS А вообще, вот тот пример о котором речь

http://www.fandroid.info/primer-ispolzovaniya-cardview-i-recyclerview-v-android

и  вот сорцы

https://github.com/tutsplus/Android-CardViewRecyclerView

Comment: Карточки, если не ошибаюсь, были представлены гуглом вместе с материал дизайном. Это было ещё до выхода 5 андроида. Для младших версий `CardView` есть в `support-v7` либе. Ни `canvas` ни `GridView` не потребуются. В ссылке-примере про `RecyclerView`, а вопрос про `ListView`